# Crop image using GD library

Tags: perl, gd

I am using GD library in my Perl script that allows me to draw a true-type-font text. Because I don't know exact size at the beginning, I set

```
my $i = new GD::Image(3000, 3000);
```

and then I draw my text

```
my $black = $i->colorAllocate(0, 0, 0);
my @b = $i->stringFT($black, './ttf/cour.ttf', 12, 0, 0, 0, "\n$text");
```

where `@b` contains my crop data.

I wish to execute something like this (incorrect syntax):

```
$i->crop(0, 0, $b[2], $b[3]);
```

...but there is no such `crop` function available.

How can I crop my image? Is there some known work-around?

Answer (score 1):

Typically you would use [the "copy" methods of `GD`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?GD#Image_Copying_Commands) to move selected data from one image into a new image.

Or if what you really need is just to compute the width and height of a strings drawn with `GD`, check out [`GD::Text`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?GD%3a%3aText).

Comment: Yeah, that is simple solution I can see as well. I am looking for some 'smart' solution that would not waste resources...